# converting an array of signed bytes to unsigned bytes

Tags: java, unsigned

I have a array of bytes.

```
bytes[] = [43, 0, 0, -13, 114, -75, -2, 2, 20, 0, 0]
```

I want to convert it to unsigned bytes in Java.
this is what I did: created a new array and copy the values with & 0xFF:

```
    this.bytes = new byte[bytes.length];
    for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++)
        this.bytes[i] = (byte) (bytes[i] & 0xFF);
```

but the values stay negative in the new array as well.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no unsigned bytes in Java.

Comment: What do you expect an operation like ``byteValue & 0xFF`` to do?

Comment: @f1sh It does the right thing in terms of converting a signed byte into an unsiged `int`. If you just cast a byte with a negative value e.g. into an `int` you end up with an `int` with that negative number. So that part of the code wasn't the problem, just the one where it's put back (i.e. casted again) into a `byte` ending up with the same negative value you started with.

Answer (score 14):

`bytes` in Java are always signed.

If you want to obtained the unsigned value of these bytes, you can store them in an `int` array:

```
byte[] signed = {43, 0, 0, -13, 114, -75, -2, 2, 20, 0, 0};
int[] unsigned = new int[signed.length];
for (int i = 0; i < signed.length; i++) {
    unsigned[i] = signed[i] & 0xFF;
}
```

You'll get the following values:

```
[43, 0, 0, 243, 114, 181, 254, 2, 20, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I understand. thanks! in python there is, that's why got mistaken..

Answer (score 1):

Java has no thing called an unsigned byte. You have to use other types like `short` or `int` to be able to hold values > 127.