# How to use Lambda functions to de-sign Java's signed bytes?

Tags: java, lambda, type-conversion

Extending from [converting an array of signed bytes to unsigned bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46949759/4672035), can this be performed more elegantly without the clunky for loop using Lambdas? So,

signed `byte[]` -> unsigned `int[]`

I note that there is no  `Arrays.stream(byte[])`.

Comment: Java has a [`Byte.toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte-). Honestly, I think `Stream` is a bit of overkill and a `for` loop is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can:

```
int[] unsigned = IntStream.range(0, signed.length)
                          .map(i -> signed[i] & 0xFF)
                          .toArray();
```

where signed represents the array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could achieve it using `IntStream`:

```
public static int[] toUnsignedIntArray(byte[] array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                    .map(idx -> array[idx] &  & 0xFF)
                    .toArray();
}
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470838/963881).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
int[] unsigned = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
                          .map(i -> 0x7F & bytes[i])
                          .toArray();
```